# How to use a different footer on a certain page

Tags: wordpress

I need to have a different footer on a certain page. How can I do this? I have a page called 'Partners' in the footer of this page I need to show 4 images within the footer. So i need to use a different footer which has these images or be able to somehow show the images only on that page.

First time Wordpress, so I was wondering is there anyway to make a new template with the different footer and use it on the page? I cant find it anywhere on Google. I am using the theme Vellum.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can have the images always there and just use a css declaration to specify display block only for that page:

```
footer .images{
    display:none;
}

.page-id-42 footer .images{
    display:block;
}
```

Or in wordpress footer.php template, you can use `is_page()` to determine if the block shows at all:

```
<?php
if(is_page(42)):
?>
<div class="images"> ... whatever you want ... </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

This makes the assumption the page in question has the ID of 42. You'll need to make that whatever your actual page ID is, which can be found by editing the page and looking in the URL.

[wordpress is_page docs found here.](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_page/)